# How to start up pyspark via IPython?

Tags: macos, pyspark, ipython

I am using `pyspark --driver-memory 16G --executor-memory 16G --executor-cores 8` to start up my pyspark interpreter to execute pyspark codes. How can I start up pyspark in ipython environment, with the same configure?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using macOS or linux first you need to install jupyter notebook on the system,

```
sudo pip install notebook
```

Next you need to configure your spark home and instruct it to start the jupyter-notebook with spark configured enviornment when the command pyspark is called instead of starting the pyspark shell.

I have my spark located at /usr/local/ and depending on where your spark is located change the path to your SPARK_HOME,

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark/
export PATH="$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH="$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH"

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

Command lsited above have to be pasted into your .bash_profile if you are using mac or .bashrc file if you are using linux. The file is located in your home directory, use cd to go there.

Once .bashrc has been edited, use

```
source .bashrc
```

or .bash_profile if you have mac to bring enviornment changes into an affect.

After that just use

```
pyspark
```

and that will trigger a notebook for you where you can edit your code.